# Convert Word to PDF - barcode font not displayed

Tags: pdf, .net-3.5, docx, aspose.words

I am using `Aspose.Words.dll` to convert word Doc to PDF

Here is my code

```
var fileName = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory 
               + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
File.WriteAllBytes(fileName + ".docx", wordBytes);
var doc = new Aspose.Words.Document(fileName + ".docx");
doc.Save(fileName + ".pdf");
```

If i run the above code **it successfully convert Word to PDF**.

But my problem is i have bar-code font in my word and that was not show in PDF. In-spite of bar-code it displays the letter in PDF Document.

*I have all fonts installed in my system.*

I have tried like below also,

```
var saveOptions = new PdfSaveOptions();
saveOptions.EmbedFullFonts = true;
doc.Save(fileName + ".pdf", saveOptions);
```

But nothing will happen.

Can any one help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you are converting your document under shared server then most probably it is a security issue. Aspose.Words for .NET DLL needs access to the Windows registry, to find the fonts folder. Refer to http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsnet/Considerations+When+Running+on+a+Shared+Server+Environment for more details.

A workaround is also possible to specify the path of folder, which has all the required fonts. Please see http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsnet/How+to++Specify+True+Type+Fonts+Location for sample code.

If you still face problem, please report the issue in Aspose.Words forum with the input document.

I work with Aspose as Developer evangelist.